# High voltage Transmission gates

Tags: transistors, analog, high-voltage, cmos

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ2HB9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can easily implement transmission gates in Low voltage levels 5V maybe 12V but, when it comes to high voltage, like 100V many transistors can not handle  that voltage difference between Gate and Source. I've been researching this for a while and stilll can not find anything about high voltage transmission gates.

Transmission gates are very useful in many ways. They do not consume energy in static state, they are bidirectional, their ON resistance are very low. But, what I am wondering about is can I implement this structure in high voltage with same features as it has in CMOS process(low resistance, bidirectional and no static state power)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I don't think you can. For one thing, as you note, the gates will not withstand 100V so some kind of power dissipation will exist in the gate drive circuitry. It is possible to contrive some form of isolated or level shifted gate drive for the transistors and make it work.

A practical solution is often to use an opto-MOS SSR, however it will only have zero power dissipation in one state. You can get either normally open or normally closed. They are, however, rather slow and your 1kHz may not make it through unscathed.

Answer (score 3):

High voltage CMOS analog switches are available commercially:
[Ixys](http://www.ixysic.com/Products/HVAnaSwitches.htm)   [Supertex/Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/HV2301)
They generally accept low-voltage logic inputs to switch high-voltage signals.
Instead of 'transmission gates', they're described as analog switches, perhaps because the digital inputs don't accept the same HV signal levels
as are being switched.   Ultrasound systems are a typical application.